# Как обработать нулевое количество строк в результате работы Dapper и вывести табличку "Не найдено"

Tags: c#, bootstrap

Всем привет,
Есть проект на C#, который с помощью Dapper извлекает по запросу из базы T-SQL строки и выводит их через Bootstrap в таблицу

Это HomeController.cs

```
var ALL = dbi.ExecuteReader(sqlQuery2);

                            DataTable table = new DataTable();
                            table.Load(ALL);
                            int rcount = table.Rows.Count;
                            ViewBag.trc = rcount;
```

Это Index.cshtml

```
@if (@ViewBag.trc != null)
        {

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <td>@row[i]</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

        }
```

Вопрос: если sqlQuery2 не находит ничего (то есть rcount = 0), то как сказать Bootstrap'у, чтобы он вывел поверх существующего окна новое с "Ничего не найдено" и кнопкой "ОК", которая бы возвращала в начало?